# AngularJS Jasmine spyOn: number is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I am having trouble running a test that uses a mockup for a service call (retrieve a location from the web sql database).

This is the controller:

.controller('LocationDetailCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams, LocationDbService, ProjectDbService) {

```
    $scope.getLocation = function () {

        LocationDbService.get($stateParams.locationId,
            //Success
            function (tx, results) {

                console.log(JSON.stringify(results.rows.item(0)));

                if (results.rows.length > 0) {
                    console.log("We are in the if statement");
                    $scope.location = {
                        id: results.rows.item(0).id,
                        name: results.rows.item(0).name,
                        address: results.rows.item(0).address,
                        lat: results.rows.item(0).latitude,
                        lng: results.rows.item(0).longitude,
                        radius: results.rows.item(0).radius
                    }
                    $scope.$apply();
                }
            },
            //Error
            function () {
                console.log("Could not retrieve the location");
            })
    }
```

Before each test:

```
var ctrl, scope, locationDbService, projectDbService, stateparams;
// inject the $controller and $rootScope services
// in the beforeEach block
beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, _LocationDbService_, _ProjectDbService_) {
    // Create a new scope that's a child of the $rootScope
    scope = $rootScope.$new();

    stateparams = {locationId: 1}; //mock your stateparams object with your id

    // Create the controller
    ctrl = $controller('LocationDetailCtrl', {
        $scope: scope,
        $stateParams: stateparams,
        LocationDbService: _LocationDbService_,
        ProjectDbService: _ProjectDbService_
    });
    locationDbService = _LocationDbService_;
    projectDbService = _ProjectDbService_;
}));
```

The test:

```
 it('a location should be retrieved',
    function () {
        spyOn(locationDbService, 'get').andCallFake(function(success, fail){

            var results = [];
            results.push(
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Jeroen",
                    "address": "Kontitch",
                    "latitude": "27.6648274",
                    "longitude": "-81.51575350000002",
                    "radius": 50
                });

            var rs = {
                //rs is a SQLResultSetobject
                insertId: 0,
                rowsAffected: 0,
                rows: {
                    //rows is a SQLResultSetRowListobject
                    length: results.length,
                    item: function(index) {
                        return results[index];
                    }
                }
            };

            success(null, rs);
        });

        expect(scope.location).toBeUndefined();
        scope.getLocation();
        expect(scope.location).toBeDefined();
    });
```

I get the following test failure:

[image: Number is not a function]

Does somebody know why I get this error? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that you can use angular.mock.inject to mock your own service for you. I have always created an object that has the needed fields/functions on it to mock the service via  spies.
Inject what you can:

```
inject(function ($controller, $rootScope)
```

mock what you can't

```
stateparams = {locationId: 1};
locationDbService = jasmine.createSpyObj('LocationDbService', ['method1', 'method2']);
projectDbService= jasmine.createSpyObj('ProjectDbService', ['method3', 'method4']);
```

Then create your controller with these:

```
ctrl = $controller('LocationDetailCtrl', {
    $scope: scope,
    $stateParams: stateparams,
    LocationDbService: locationDbService ,
    ProjectDbService: projectDbService
});
```

This way you have full control over what is being injected into your controller to truly isolate it for your unit test.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can you please take a look at my solution, is the the correct way to go.

Regarding your solution, how/where do I implement the methods, for example method1?

Answer (score 0):

I've created following mock in the beforeEach:

```
        locationDbServiceMock = {
        get: function (index,cbsuccess, cberror) {
            var results = [];
            results.push(
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Jeroen",
                    "address": "Kontitch",
                    "latitude": "27.6648274",
                    "longitude": "-81.51575350000002",
                    "radius": 50
                });

            var rs = {
                //rs is a SQLResultSetobject
                insertId: 0,
                rowsAffected: 0,
                rows: {
                    //rows is a SQLResultSetRowListobject
                    length: results.length,
                    item: function (index) {
                        return results[index];
                    }
                }
            };

            cbsuccess(null, rs);
        }
    };
```

I just inject this mocked service into my controller and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I've found what was wrong with my code, I forgot the index parameter:

U can use this:

```
function (locId, success, fail)
```

Or my mockup object in the other answer